# Why doesn't this different method of calling an AJAX request fail?

Tags: javascript

This is the code from my site: view-source:http://davidjamal.webng.com/DavidGodfrey/ajax_request.html

If you need another source, here: http://jsfiddle.net/rXkxa/

I'm not calling the AJAX request on JSFiddle's site. I'm just posting the code there simply to show you. When I try to call the request using `HTTPRequest.dispatch();`, it returns this error:

`Unsafe JavaScript attempt to access frame with URL http://davidjamal.webng.com/DavidGodfrey/ajax_request.html from frame with URL http://ad.adnetwork.net/st?ad_type=iframe&ad_size=728x90&section=1912997. Domains, protocols and ports must match.`

Comment: I'd imagine that error is from the ads on your website, rather than your code.

Comment: So my code is correct? It's just the ads interfering?

Comment: Yeah, that's what it looks like.

Comment: So is there any way to do this without having to take down the ads because if I do that then I lose my site.

Comment: It's not actually causing an error in your code. Your code should continue running without errors. All it's going to do it have an annoying little error in your console, but not much else.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For security reasons, you can only access frames on the same domain as you with javascript.  Your particular error looks like an ad frame trying to access a frame that does not belong to it.

On the jsfiddle you posted, it doesn't actually run anything.  Usually, one can press the Run button and see the error you're talking about.  How do you expect us to use the fiddle?